# Divergence of this series

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I don't know how to solve this:
Fix a positive real number $k$ and set $p=1/k$. For $n \ge 0$, consider the function $f_n : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by $f_n(z)=k^n z^n$.

Fix $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\mid z_0\mid \ge p$. Show that the numerical series $\sum_{n\ge0}f_n(z_0)$ diverges.

Comment: Is $k$ greater than $1$?

Comment: $k$ is an arbitrary positive real number.

Answer (score 2):

To show that the series diverges, we show that $ f_n(z_0)$ does not converge to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. This common test for divergence of real series also works for series of complex numbers.

To show this, simply notice that for any $n$,
$$
|f_n(z_0)| = \left|k^n z_0^n\right| = k^n \;  \left|z_0 \right|^n.
$$
As $\left|z_0 \right| \geq p = 1/k$, we must have that $k \left|z_0 \right| \geq 1$, and so $  k^n \;  \left|z_0 \right|^n$ must be at least $1$, too. Thus $f_n(z_0)$ always is at least distance $1$ away from $0$, and so cannot converge to it.